# Combination of macros behaving unusually

Tags: c, macros, free

Following the advice of Reese's *Understanding and Using C Pointers*, I defined a 'safe free' combination of function and macro, as follows:

```
#define safeFree(p) saferFree((void*)&(p))

void saferFree(void **pp) {
    if (pp !=NULL && *pp !=NULL) {
        free(*pp);
        *pp = NULL;
    }
}
```

Then, following the advice of Klawonn's *21st Century C*, I also defined the 'apply to list' macro as follows:

```
#define Fn_apply(type, fn, ...) {    \
    void *stopper_for_apply = (int[]){0};    \
    type **list_for_apply = (type*[]){__VA_ARGS__, stopper_for_apply};    \
    for (int i = 0; list_for_apply[i] != stopper_for_apply; i++) {    \
        fn(list_for_apply[i]);    \
    }    \
```

These are both defined in one file. Then, in another file (which includes these), I have a struct, which contains an internal array which is dynamically allocated. Now, I've defined a custom deallocation function for this struct, which looks roughly like this:

```
void deallocate (S** s_ptr) {
    safeFree((*s_ptr)->arr); //deallocates the array
    safeFree(*s_ptr); //deallocates the struct
}
```

Now, I've tested it with the following code:

```
S* foo = allocate(); //allocates a new struct, makes the internal array as well
deallocate(&foo);
assert(!foo);
```

With the above `deallocate`, this passes. However, if I change `deallocate` to this:

```
void deallocate (S** s_ptr) {
    Fn_apply(void, safeFree, (*s_ptr)->arr, *s_ptr);
}
```

The memory gets removed fine, but the assertion above fails. Did I miss something?

Comment: in your function you have parameter `p`, but use `pp`?

Comment: Your new version of `deallocate` applies `safeFree` to all the array elements, but it never frees `s_ptr` itself.

Comment: Typo, my bad. Fixed now.

Comment: First: I doubt you have actually copy/pasted your actual code, since there are things in the one here that will simply not compile. Also, in the expansion of the macro the code will basically be saferFree( &list_for_apply[i] ). Note that the pointer in the array will be set to null, not in the initial variable

Comment: @perh: So does that mean that, if I use ``Fn_apply``, the ``fn`` argument must be a function and not a macro call?

Comment: @perh `Fn_apply` is a macro, so it replaces `fn` with `safeFree` in `fn(list_for_apply[i])`, so it IS in a function-call-like context.

Comment: I missed that Fn_apply would expand. Anyway, @Barmar indicates the issue here, the pointer that will be passes is &list_to_apply[i], so the pointer that will be set to NULL is in the element in the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created this compilable code from your question:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct S
{
    int *arr;
} S;

#define safeFree(p) saferFree((void *) & (p))

extern S *allocate(void);
extern void saferFree(void **p);
extern void deallocate(S **s_ptr);
extern void deallocate2(S **s_ptr);
extern void function(void);

void saferFree(void **pp)
{
    if (pp != NULL && *pp != NULL)
    {
        free(*pp);
        *pp = NULL;
    }
}

#define Fn_apply(type, fn, ...) {    \
        void *stopper_for_apply = (int[]){0};    \
        type **list_for_apply = (type *[]){__VA_ARGS__, stopper_for_apply};    \
        for (int i = 0; list_for_apply[i] != stopper_for_apply; i++) {    \
            fn(list_for_apply[i]);    \
        } }

void deallocate(S **s_ptr)
{
    safeFree((*s_ptr)->arr); // deallocates the array
    safeFree(*s_ptr); // deallocates the struct
}

void function(void)
{
    S *foo = allocate(); // allocates a new struct, makes the internal array as well
    deallocate(&foo);
    assert(!foo);
}

void deallocate2(S **s_ptr)
{
    Fn_apply(void, safeFree, (*s_ptr)->arr, *s_ptr);
}
```

I ran the preprocessor on it, and then formatted the section from the structure definition onwards.  That gives:

```
typedef struct S
{
    int *arr;
} S;


extern S *allocate(void);
extern void saferFree(void **p);
extern void deallocate(S **s_ptr);
extern void deallocate2(S **s_ptr);
extern void function(void);

void saferFree(void **pp)
{
    if (pp != ((void *)0) && *pp != ((void *)0))
    {
        free(*pp);
        *pp = ((void *)0);
    }
}

# 33 "fz.c"
void deallocate(S **s_ptr)
{
    saferFree((void *) &((*s_ptr)->arr));
    saferFree((void *) &(*s_ptr));
}

void function(void)
{
    S *foo = allocate();
    deallocate(&foo);
    (__builtin_expect(!(!foo), 0) ? __assert_rtn(__func__, "fz.c", 43, "!foo") : (void)0);
}

void deallocate2(S **s_ptr)
{
    {
        void *stopper_for_apply = (int[]){0};
        void **list_for_apply = (void *[]){
            (*s_ptr)->arr, *s_ptr, stopper_for_apply
        };
        for (int i = 0; list_for_apply[i] != stopper_for_apply; i++)
        {
            saferFree((void *) &(list_for_apply[i]));
        }
    }
}
```

This code confused Uncrustify 0.60 into producing uncompilable code; it botched the formatting of the two array literals, losing the trailing semicolons.

I think the output shows the problem.  You're working with copies of the `(*s_ptr)->arr` and `*s_ptr` in the `list_for_apply` array, rather than the originals.  So, the two lots of code simply make different assumptions about what's going on, and therefore come to the wrong conclusion.

Comment: Is there a way I can get around this, or am I gonna have to pass the original pointers (i.e. calling ``safeFree`` multiple times manually)?

Comment: I think you will have to write out the calls manually or use something other than `Fn_apply` to do the work.  Personally, for the 'inner' calls to `free()`, I do not see much advantage to the safer variant.  I can see some benefit to it for the top-level operation, the one in the code written by the user, but even that is not a panacea; it can only nullify one pointer to the data, but if there are several pointers to a given piece of data, there will still be opportunities to use a dangling pointer to freed memory.

Comment: Yes, in general the "saferFree" is anything but. But that was not really the question. :)